# Issue creating a Glue job on AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-cdk

i am trying to add default arguments to a glue job on AWS CDK, specifically the bookmark option enabled. keep on getting the same error:

`Error: Resolution error: Supplied properties not correct for "CfnJobProps" defaultArguments: "--job-bookmark-option: job-bookmark-enable" should be an 'object'.`

my bode is below:

```
    glueETLJob = _glue.CfnJob(
        self,
        glueJobName,
        command =_glue.CfnJob.JobCommandProperty(
            name = glueJobName,
            python_version= '3',
            script_location = config_bucket_arn + "/code/gluejob.py"
        ),
        role=glueJobRole.role_arn,
        glue_version='1.0',
        max_retries=0,
        timeout=30,
        security_configuration=glueSecurityConfiguration.ref,
        default_arguments=str("--job-bookmark-option: job-bookmark-enable"),
        description="glue job"
    )
```

Comment: can you try  default_arguments={
            '--job-bookmark-option': 'job-bookmark-enable'
        },

Comment: seems to be working fine receiving a dictionary, thanks @PrabhakarReddy

Answer (score 8):

As the error indicates you need to pass default_arguments as an object as shown below :

```
default_arguments={ '--job-bookmark-option': 'job-bookmark-enable' }
```

It is weird though as CDK Guide says that you can pass `any` data type but [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-job.html) doc here says it has to be `JSON` for `default_arguments`

Also filed https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cdk-guide/issues/251 to confirm and update the doc if required.